# Batch: Proceed with files from previous loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to modify this batch script, but have no idea how to preceed. Now it's converting every SVG file in the folder and then merging all the PDF files in the folder. My goal would be to convert every SVG file in the folder and merge only the converted files.
Can this be done with SET, should it be done before or after the conversion or maybe there's another trick I'm not aware of?

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in ("*.svg") do %inkscape% "%%i" --export-pdf="%%~ni.pdf"
for %%i in ("*.pdf") do (set command=!command! "%%i")
%pdftk% %command% cat output "%name%.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in ("*.svg") do (
   %inkscape% "%%i" --export-pdf="%%~ni.pdf"
   set command=!command! "%%~ni.pdf"
)
%pdftk% %command% cat output "%name%.pdf"
```